# Unable to feed verbatim ampersand into tblr (tabularray) environment using Lua code

Tags: luatex, tabularray

I am trying to write into a `tblr` environment using Lua code. My actual code is meant to generate the rows one by one. But the MWE given here attempts it with a single line from `\directlua`, by calling `tex.print`.

I also tried to use `tex.sprint`, but `tex.print` seems more appropriate, going by the documentation.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{c|c|c|c}
        \directlua{ tex.print([[ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ ]], "") }
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
> Step: init table outer spec.
> Step: parse table options.
> Step: split table.
> Step: init table inner spec.
> Step: parse table inner spec.
> Step: execute table commands.
> Step: calculate cell and line sizes.

! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.1  1 &
       2 & 3 & 4 \\
l.12     \end
           {tblr}
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

Switching the `tblr` for `tabular` will also make this work again, but I need `tblr`/`tabularray` for some of its features. This also seems to indicate that `&` somehow is treated in a way that puts printing it via `\directlua` at odds with `tabularray`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in your example `\begin{tblr}[expand=\directlua]{c|c|c|c}` work, but generally expanding commands inside a tblr is hard work, it is probably better to build the table content first before the tblr.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Indeed it works with `[expand=\directlua]`. But before I run off, attempting something that has the next pitfall already waiting for me ... what do you mean by building the table content before? As in building it into a LaTeX macro and then passing that via `expand=` and as the table body?